# Can I play an Xbox One Fifa 17 on an Xbox 360 too?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, fifa-17

If I buy fifa 17 for xbox one will it also play on 360?

Comment: Why would you even think that's possible?

Answer (score 5):

No. The game does not work across consoles like that (and neither do most other games).